# Como atribuir novo valor de SelectOneMenu para entidade?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Tenho uma tabela com várias colunas, entre elas tenho uma que é um `SelectOneMenu`, a tabela é carregada com uma lista de `Inscricao`.

Na coluna de status da inscrição tenho um `SelectOneMenu` com os status: `{"Solicitada","Deferida","Indeferida"}`. Por padrão cada inscrição ao ser realizada contém o status 0, ou seja "Solicitada", assim quero trocar o estado da inscrição em uma listagem quando o usuário escolher uma opção diferente do status que está atualmente na inscrição.

O problema é que não consigo ter o id da Inscrição e o novo valor ao mesmo tempo, assim eu não consigo mudar o valor de status da inscrição.

"`i`" é uma variável que contém uma lista de inscrições:

```xml
<p:column headerText="StatusAdmin" filterBy="#{i.status}" filterMatchMode="contains" rendered="#{p:ifGranted('admin')}" >
    <p:selectOneMenu id="statusSelectOneMenu" value="#{i.status}" style="width:125px" 
            onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{inscricaoBean.editarInscricao(i)}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Solicitada" itemValue="0" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Deferida" itemValue="1" /> 
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Indeferida" itemValue="2" />   
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
```

Desta forma:

```
valueChangeListener="#{inscricaoBean.evt}"
```

Tenho acesso ao novo valor que foi atribuído, mas neste caso não sei qual a inscrição relacionada à este novo valor.

```
valueChangeListener="#{inscricaoBean.evt(i)}"
```

Desta forma tenho acesso à inscrição, mas não sei qual o novo valor, como faço para ter os dois ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 3):

Tente o seguinte:

Remova `onchange="submit()"` e `valueChangeListener="#{inscricaoBean.editarInscricao(i)}"`do seu `<p:selectOneMenu>` e dentro dele adicione:

```
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="{inscricaoBean.editarInscricao(i)}" />
```

Ficando assim:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="statusSelectOneMenu" value="#{i.status}" style="width:125px">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Solicitada" itemValue="0" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Deferida" itemValue="1" /> 
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Indeferida" itemValue="2" />   
                        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="{inscricaoBean.editarInscricao(i)}" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Ao adicionar isso quando você selecionar uma nova opção ele já vai processar esse valor e setar na sua variável `i` e depois vai chamar seu método `editarInscricao()`, assim já vai ter o novo valor.